# Unable to start xampp on mac os sierra?

Tags: php, macos, server, xampp, macos-sierra

I have installed xampp on my mac os sierra.Now when i try start the server it shows me some error.It does not start.I have tried restarting & reinstalling the server but still i am facing the issue.

```
 failed to start machine: hyperkit: [ERROR] Found a reference to cluster 19715 outside the file (max cluster 19711) from cluster 4.2165
    hyperkit: [ERROR] Mirage block device raised exception: Qcow.Make(Base)(Time).Reference_outside_file(_, _)
    Mirage-block error: Block device is disconnected
    Could not open mirage-block device: Invalid argument

Could not open backing file: Invalid argument
```

I am not able to find any solution. Please suggest what should i do ?

Comment: Looks like a docker issue. https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1602

Comment: what is a dokcer ?

Comment: No such file in my system.Please tell me more.I am not able to resolve this issue yet

Answer (score 2):

Although i could not fix this particular error with xammpp software.This xampp software was **XAMPP-VM / PHP 7.1.7**.So i deleted this software from my machine and downloaded another version of xampp which is **7.1.7 / PHP** 7.1.7.Actually there are 4 software listed on the xampp website earlier i download the VM version of xampp.But after intsalling another version of XAMPP solved my problem.

[image]